# df index to hour (can't use to.datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I want to add new column 'time' which are the convertion form index, e.g. 1 to 01:00, 2 to 02:00 (for **hour**). I tried to datetime but it resulted to full date and index only turns into second.

```
df['time'] = df.index

          prob       time
0   9.172968e-01      0
1   8.585100e-01      1
2   7.957514e-01      2
3   7.239329e-01      3
4   6.729420e-01      4
5   6.187557e-01      5
6   5.572768e-01      6
```

Expected result:

```
        prob          time
0   9.172968e-01      00:00
1   8.585100e-01      01:00
2   7.957514e-01      02:00
3   7.239329e-01      03:00
4   6.729420e-01      04:00
5   6.187557e-01      05:00
6   5.572768e-01      06:00
```

Comment: what happens when the index becomes 24?

Comment: it should be no problem since it will be needed to show how many hours left to some event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `to_timedelta` with `unit` m

```
df['time']=pd.to_timedelta(df.index,unit='m')
df
Out[456]: 
       prob     time
0  0.917297 00:00:00
1  0.858510 00:01:00
2  0.795751 00:02:00
3  0.723933 00:03:00
4  0.672942 00:04:00
5  0.618756 00:05:00
6  0.557277 00:06:00
```

Comment: this works! and i tried the unit to hour too, great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this works.

```
df = df.assign(time = [ datetime.datetime.strptime(str(val),'%H').strftime('%H-%M') if val < 24 else  datetime.datetime.strptime(str(val%24),'%H').strftime('%H-%M') for val in df.index.values])
```